# replaced "-lmkl_em64t" by "-lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core" -> "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" fortran

Tags: macos, fortran, undefined-symbol

I am trying to compile Fortran code on Mac OS X 10.9.3, using intel's Fortran compiler and get this error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lmkl_em64t
```

When I replace `-lmkl_em64t`  by `-lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core`, [as suggested here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-for-easily-migrating-from-mkl-9x-to-10x)

I am getting another error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks,
Heini

=======Here the complete error message:

```
ifort  -I../include -I../include -I../pdummylib -I../pdummylib -L./i686-apple-darwin9 -L../lib/i686-apple-darwin9 -L../lib/i686-apple-darwin9 -o i686-apple-darwin9/aoforce i686-apple-darwin9/fit9.o i686-apple-darwin9/aoforce.o   -lparalib -laoforcelib -lecplib -lescflib -ltraflib -lrelaxlib -lstatptlib -lutilmod -lcosmolib -lsymlib -ldscflib -lgradlib -ldftlib -laoforcelib -lridftlib -llochyblib -lmultlib -lrilib -lintlib -lutilib -lalgebralib -lsymlib -lutilmod -lclib -lmolochlib -lreleaslib -L/usr/lib -lmkl_lapack -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lpthread -lpdummylib -lutilib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_atomic_float8_max", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlansy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlansy_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zlanhe in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zlanhe_par.o)
  "___kmpc_barrier", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_row in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_col in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_bcopy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_with_copy_0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_abcopy_abx_m_km_par_p in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_xgemm_p in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_critical", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dsbrdbm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsbrdbm_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaeh2 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaeh2_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dsbrdbn in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsbrdbn_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zhbrdbm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zhbrdbm_par.o)
  "___kmpc_dispatch_fini_8", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
  "___kmpc_dispatch_init_8", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dormql in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dormql_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dormqr in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dormqr_par.o)
  "___kmpc_dispatch_next_8", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dormql in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dormql_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dormqr in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dormqr_par.o)
  "___kmpc_end_critical", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dsbrdbm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsbrdbm_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaeh2 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaeh2_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dsbrdbn in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsbrdbn_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zhbrdbm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zhbrdbm_par.o)
  "___kmpc_end_master", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_zhemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zhemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_zgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zgemv_omp.o)
  "___kmpc_end_ordered", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
  "___kmpc_end_reduce_nowait", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlansy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlansy_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zlanhe in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zlanhe_par.o)
  "___kmpc_end_serialized_parallel", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dsyrk in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsyrk_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dtrsm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dtrsm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_daxpy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(daxpy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dcopy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dcopy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_ddot_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(ddot_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_end_single", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf_ib in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_ib_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlatrd in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlatrd_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dsytd3 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsytd3_par.o)
      _mkl_blas_zgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zhetd3 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zhetd3_par.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_flush", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
  "___kmpc_for_static_fini", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlacpy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlacpy_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaset in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaset_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaswp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaswp_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlatrd in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlatrd_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dorgql in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dorgql_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dorgqr in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dorgqr_par.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_4", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlatrd in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlatrd_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zlatrd in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zlatrd_par.o)
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_8", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlacpy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlacpy_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaset in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaset_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaswp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaswp_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dorgql in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dorgql_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dorgqr in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dorgqr_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlaeh2 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaeh2_par.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_fork_call", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dsyrk in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsyrk_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dtrsm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dtrsm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_daxpy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(daxpy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dcopy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dcopy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_ddot_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(ddot_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_global_thread_num", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_row in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_col in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_bcopy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_with_copy_0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_abcopy_abx_m_km_par_p in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_xgemm_p in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_master", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_zhemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zhemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_zgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zgemv_omp.o)
  "___kmpc_ok_to_fork", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dsyrk in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsyrk_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dtrsm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dtrsm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_daxpy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(daxpy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dcopy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dcopy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_ddot_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(ddot_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_ordered", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlaed0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlaed0_par.o)
  "___kmpc_push_num_threads", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dsyrk in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsyrk_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dtrsm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dtrsm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_daxpy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(daxpy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dcopy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dcopy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_ddot_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(ddot_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_reduce_nowait", referenced from:
      _mkl_lapack_dlansy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlansy_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zlanhe in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zlanhe_par.o)
  "___kmpc_serialized_parallel", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dsyrk in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsyrk_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dtrsm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dtrsm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_daxpy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(daxpy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dcopy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dcopy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_ddot_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(ddot_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_single", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dgetrf_ib in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgetrf_ib_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dlatrd in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dlatrd_par.o)
      _mkl_lapack_dsytd3 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsytd3_par.o)
      _mkl_blas_zgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_lapack_zhetd3 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(zhetd3_par.o)
      ...
  "_omp_get_dynamic_", referenced from:
      _get_dynamic_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_get_max_threads", referenced from:
      _mkl_serv_get_max_threads in libmkl_intel_thread.a(mkl_threading.o)
      _mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads in libmkl_intel_thread.a(mkl_threading.o)
  "_omp_get_max_threads_", referenced from:
      _get_max_threads_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_get_num_procs_", referenced from:
      _get_num_procs_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_get_num_threads", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dsyrk in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dsyrk_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dtrsm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dtrsm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_daxpy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(daxpy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dcopy_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dcopy_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_ddot_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(ddot_omp.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemv_omp in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemv_omp.o)
      ...
  "_omp_get_num_threads_", referenced from:
      _get_num_threads_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
      _mkl_blas_dgemm in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_row in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_col in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_bsrc in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_bcopy in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_1d_with_copy_0 in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      _mkl_blas_dgemm_2d_abcopy_abx_m_km_par_p in libmkl_intel_thread.a(dgemm_drv.o)
      ...
  "_omp_get_thread_num_", referenced from:
      _get_thread_num_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_in_parallel", referenced from:
      _mkl_serv_get_max_threads in libmkl_intel_thread.a(mkl_threading.o)
      _mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads in libmkl_intel_thread.a(mkl_threading.o)
      _mkl_serv_omp_in_parallel in libmkl_intel_thread.a(mkl_threading.o)
     (maybe you meant: _mkl_serv_omp_in_parallel)
  "_omp_in_parallel_", referenced from:
      _in_parallel_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_set_dynamic_", referenced from:
      _set_dynamic_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_set_nested_", referenced from:
      _set_nested_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
  "_omp_set_num_threads_", referenced from:
      _set_num_threads_ in libutilib.a(ompwrap.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
make[1]: *** [i686-apple-darwin9/aoforce] Error 1
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

Comment: Please show the compete error message, or at least more from it. I suggest to ask on the official support forum at Intel.

Comment: The complete error message is very long, here is more:

Comment: edit the question with the new information, do not use a comment.

Comment: Did you try asking Intel?

Comment: Yes, I sent them a message, now waiting for a reply.